# Shapes control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there anything like shapes control of VB 6.0, in Vb.Net?
I need to draw lines etc. at design time.  But I could not find any shapes control in the toolbox.

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft released the free [Microsoft Visual Basic Power Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb735936) that contains Line and Shape controls that you can add to the tool box. A [post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/07/24/visual-basic-power-packs-is-included-in-visual-studio-2008-sp1.aspx) suggests it is included in VS2008 SP1 so you may already have it.

Alternatively you can create your own using a panel and override the onPaint event.

Answer (score 1):

no built in controls but you can easily achieve the same goal with some API calls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw12xs4(v=VS.90).aspx